# Load Json Into Recyclerview item with Spinner

Tags: java, php, android

I have two arrays

1. Android
2. PriceWeight

where Android is whole view and `PriceWeight` I want to show in spinner (Weight or Price).
I have done fetching it just problem is fetching data in spinner.

JSON Link 
http://navsarimarket.com/API/getProductPriceWeight.php?Category=77

[image: Output of My Example]

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over your JSON and make a string list something like below

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray androidArray = obj.getJSONArray("Android");

for(int count=0; count<androidArray.length(); count++){
     JSONObject inner  = androidArray.get(count);
     JSONArray weight = inner.getJSONArray("PriceWeight");
     List<String> spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(int i=0; i<weight.length(); i++){
       JSONObject temp = weight.get(i);
       String value = temp.getString("Weight");
       value = value + " - " + temp.getString("Price");
       //pass this to your recyclerview model for showing spinner per row.
       spinnerArrayList.add(value);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onBindViewHolder add below code where **list** is list of data you get from JSON response which will display in your spinner.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("TEST");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            holder.siteSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.siteSpinner);
            holder.siteSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
```